# Generate n words from a json server by user input using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I just started to practice Javascript and I have a json file with a bunch of words. I want to **display as many words as the given user input**. If user input is 4 then 4 words will be displayed randomly from the server. **I can successfully get the data from te server and display all of them in a table** but the logic of displaying random words from the server is a little difficult for the firs try and **I would like to get a better understanding how to approach it** in my case. The `getRandomWords()` function is where I was trying to approach something.

**words.json**

```
{
"words":
[
"a",
"abandon",
"ability",
"able",
"abortion",
"about",
"above",
"abroad",
"absence",
"absolute",
"absolutely",
"absorb",
"abuse",
"academic"
]
}
```

**snippet from project.js**

```
function getServerData(url) {
  let fetchOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "no-cache"
  };
  return fetch(url, fetchOptions).then(
    response => response.json(),
    err => console.error(err)
  );
}
document.querySelector("#server-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  getServerData("http://localhost:3000/words").then(
    data => fillDataTable(data, "wordTable")
  );
});

function getRandomWords() {
  let words = getServerData("http://localhost:3000/words").then(
    data => randomWordExample(data)
  );
  var howManyWords = document.querySelector("#words-to-memorize");
  const randomElement = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  console.log("random words: ", randomElement);
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="words-to-memorize">How many words you want to see?</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="words-to-memorize">
          </div>
          <button id="get-words-button" class="button btn btn-block btn-primary">
            Get the words
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working solution finally was the following:

```
function getRandomWords() {
    let words = getServerData('http://localhost:3000/words').then(data => {
        const wordsToMemorize = document.querySelector('#words-to-memorize');
        document.querySelector("#wordsInput").addEventListener("click", function() {
            let temp = wordsToMemorize.value;
            selectedtombelemek.innerHTML = "";
            for(let i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
            let rander = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);
            selectedtombelemek.innerHTML += data[rander] + "</br>";
        }})
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRandomWords () {
  let words = getServerData("http://localhost:3000/words").then(
    data => randomWorldExample(data)
  );
  let howManyWords = document.querySelector("#words-to-memorize");
  let randomElement = words[0].words.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
  console.log("random words: ", randomElement.slice(0, howManyWords));
}
```

This should get ya there. What we are doing is randomly sorting the array then we are slicing the array to the n value.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation (+1). It still doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure if I assigned well `getServerData()` to `words` since I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'words' of undefined
    at getRandomWords`.

Comment: yeah your getting into Promises here, check out this link, it goes over promises and async/await lightly
https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp

Comment: let words = getServerData('http://localhost:3000/words').then((resp) => {
    let howManyWords = document.querySelector('#words-to-memorize')
    let randomElement = resp[0].words.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
    return randomElement.slice(0, howManyWords)
  })

this should set words to the random words for you

Comment: I checked it closer and `words.sort` is the source of the error message: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: words is not defined`